# Как поменять стиль для тега

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span class="vote-list-progress-bg" style="display:none;">
```

Как с помощью js сделать `span` видимым, т.е. убрать `display:none`

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vote-list-progress-bg")[0].style.display="";
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` ищет элементы по имени *тега*, а Вы пытаетесь искать по *классу*. Вероятно, это опечатка и нужна функция `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Так, черт возьми, и есть! Наверно пора завязывать отвечать на стаке в рабочее время, слишком уж я невнимателен :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.vote-list-progress-bg').show()
```

Answer (score 2):

и еще вариант, с [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('.vote-list-progress-bg').style.display = '';
```